# Only some css being used

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-float

I'm extremely puzzled and coming for help.  I'm editing a Wordpress theme and within 5 lines of the css it just stops "reading" it.

I cannot post an example in jsfiddle or cssdesk due to me using captions in Wordpress and that isn't supported.

Also, what bugs me, is that this was working earlier.  Went to dinner, now it's not.

http://continuum.theneocloud.com/echo-pedicure-chair/

Is the dev site.  It should be 3 rows of pictures on the bottom, with the headers in between.  Like I said, worked before.  The browser is seeing the css file, as I can go to inspect element, and see the stylesheet being loaded.

Example problem:  The headers aren't clearing floats, the bottom pictures aren't floating, even though the css is correct.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to be able to help you.

Comment: When your css is not completing to read the rest of a document you wanna go check when did it work and what have i done since? Go back trough that css and look for komma's, semicolons, curlybrackets and other syntax markers

Comment: My apologies.  Assumed you could check in Firebug or something.  From now on I won't assume.  Up arrow for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 1522 of [this file](http://continuum.theneocloud.com/wp-content/themes/Karma/style.css), you have this declaration:

```
#content ol li, #content ul li, .content_full_width ol li, , .content_full_width ul li {margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

There's an extra comma there, creating a parse error.

Furthermore, on line 20 of [this file](http://continuum.theneocloud.com/wp-content/themes/Karma/css/shutter.css), you're ending the rule with a right parenthesis, instead of a right brace.

```
#Echo_Plus_Upholstery_Options {float:left;margin-left:25%;)
```

Comment: This might be it! atleast its wrong if you look at css syntax and might brake it cuz css reads from top to bottom

Comment: This is what it was!  Thank you so much!  It was the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

One issue you are having is that you are not clearning your floats properly.

Add this to your CSS:

```css
h4.picture_titles{
    clear: both;
}
```

Since every `<div>` you have down there floats left (`#CurvedBase`, `#echo_options` and `#Echo_Plus_Upholstery_Options`), the following heading is off.

Comment: Why was it working before without the h4.picture_titles{ when I was just using picture_titles ?

Comment: Making that change fixed the floats though, super odd.  If you don't mind answering the question that would be amazing!

Comment: It was probably because you had images that filled the whole row that made it look like it was breaking/clearning the floats at the correct place (but not doing it). Floats are tricky at times so you really need to see to it that you clear them when needed just to keep your sanity while using them. Or go bonkers if that is your wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to all the 3 image tags.

i.e inside the `<div id="Echo_Plus_Upholstery_Options">`

```
    <div id="echo_plus_upholstery_options_black" class="wp-caption alignnone" 
style="width: 160px; float:left">
```

Comment: Thats actually all right :) you dont have to end the last tag in inline styling with semicolon

Comment: The floating left is handled by css, I didn't want to do inline as I heard that was bad.  Thank you for your help though!